# Rewrite /countries/country.php?country=usa to /countries/usa/

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to have a separate page for 50+ countries and I'm looking for a way to not have 50+ php files for each country. Ideally, I would like to rewrite:

```
/countries/country.php?country=usa
```

to this:

```
/countries/usa/
```

Currently my .htaccess looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^updates/.*\.(zip)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

It basically replaces /filename.php with /filename/

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^countries/([a-z-]+)$ /countries/country.php?country=$1 [L]
```

You can update the regular expression to your needs.

Comment: Note: This rule may need to be above the existing rules to avoid them interfering. (Especially the `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$` one, assuming you decide to add a trailing slash to the pattern to get `/countries/usa/` instead of `/countries/usa`.)